# How to write unicode letter in tex.stackexchange.com?

Tags: support

Sorry for a very layman question. After trying for more than hour, I didn't succeed in writing`\unicode{f817}`, which is a x with dot above and dot below. How we may write HERE in question ?

Comment: Did you try simply copy-pasting, and are you sure that the font used for the HTML display can show it? Sounds to me like something that might need an image if you need to show rather than describe the char.

Comment: Or perhaps you are looking for http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1272/why-doesnt-maths-render-as-maths

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use HTML entities:

> 

The above was typed as `&#xF817;`

However, glyphs in the Private Use Area (PUA), that is from U+E000 to U+F8FF don't have a predefined meaning, so the output will be unpredictable. In my case, I see a “t with bar above”, but your browser could show something else (or nothing at all).

The entity method is useful for characters outside the PUA, when you just know their code point and have no practical input method available.

In order to get an “x with dots above and below” you can use a combining character:

> ẋ̣

I typed the above by the combination `U+1E8B U+0323`, that is

> LATIN SMALL LETTER X WITH DOT ABOVE and COMBINING DOT BELOW

You can even use entities; the following was typed `&#x1E8B;&#x0323;`:

> ẋ̣

Comment: According to a quick search, this char is in the PUA so could display as anything! (I get the 'unknown char' symbol looking at your input here).

Comment: I see it as  square box. IS something wrong with my browser or what ?

Comment: @kaka Like I said, font coverage is likely to be the issue here. I'm not sure this is even a standard Unicode char (it seems to be in the 'Private Use Area'), so 'all bets are off'.

Comment: @kaka No, there's nothing wrong. The particular code point is in the Private Use Area, so its output is not predictable.

Comment: so, how to put a dot below a letter? I know \dot puts the dot above the letter , but how to put below?

Comment: @kaka `\dot` puts a dot above a letter in TeX: it's got nothing to do with showing the accent in a _question_ on the site (where you need something a web browser can render). As I say, you're likely to need an image here.

Comment: @kaka This website does not turn the LaTeX rendering on because we want to discuss about LaTeX commands and would like to see the raw input. So things like `\dot{}` etc. won't work. However, Stackexchange network supports unicode input formatting as much as it is implemented. Some of the mappings are left open for customized input so they can show different characters depending on who put what on the so-called PUA.

Comment: @percusse This has nothing to do with LaTeX rendering.

Comment: See @kaka's comment above.

Comment: @percusse ;egreg ;Joseph Wright

thanks for your time and making the clarification.

Comment: @egreg May I know that how did you combine and where did you type U+1E8B U+0323 ?

Comment: @kaka Here it is: ẋ̣. On my keyboard it's quite simple: Alt-w x Shift-Alt-x; Alt-w is for the dot above, Shift-Alt-x is for the combining dot below. Of course it depends on your keyboard and OS.

Comment: Layman way: 
1) Open the site http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/fui.html8
2) Type 1E8B and Press Enter
3) then Type 0323 and Press Enter
 Done ẋ̣ 
☺

Answer (score 4):

You can view the characters in

**Windows**: by opening the application [Character Map](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/open-character-map),

**OS X**: by opening the application [Character Palette](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1518), or

**X11**: by opening applications like [KCharSelect](http://utils.kde.org/projects/kcharselect/) if using KDE or [GNOME Character Map](https://help.gnome.org/users/gucharmap/3.4/gucharmap-getting-started.html.en) if using GNOME.